# Android App button press not functioning correctly

Tags: java, android

Being brand new to Java I'm not sure why this when called with `android:onClick="changeInfo"` isn't changing the text view back to the original value.

```
public class JavaTest extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_test);
}
public void changeInfo(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_test);
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSpace1);
    if (t.getText()==getResources().getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum)){
        t.setText("[Email Here]");
    }
    else{
        t.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum));
    }
}
```

Could anyone help, thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_test);` from the `changeInfo(View view)` method.

Comment: Thank you, much simpler fix than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_test);

- You don't have to call setContentView inside changeInfo method

> t.getText()==getResources().getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum)

- it should be `t.getText().toString().equeals(getResources().getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum))`

Try this

```
  public class JavaTest extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_test);
}
public void changeInfo(View view){

    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSpace1);
    if (t.getText().toString().equeals(getResources().getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum))){
        t.setText("[Email Here]");
    }
    else{
        t.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum));
    }
}
```